# C++ & the C arg_list functions

Tags: c++

I need to emulate a library type that allows treating it both as char* & std::string. e.g. this should be allowed:

```
char c[16];
MyString ms;
...
strcpy(c, ms);
strcpy(c, ms.c_str());
```

I only control the library but unfortunately can't change this library usage. I cannot change the printf call, just the type sent to it!

I can do this for instance by implementing:

```
class MyString : public string {
public:
    operator const char*();
};
```

The problem is with this:

```
sprintf(c, "%s", ms);
```

The C "arg_list" functions will not use the char* cast.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `std::string` decided to provide an explicit `c_str()` function instead of `operator const char*()` for a reason.  Regardless, would `sprintf(c, "%s", (const char *)ms);` be acceptable?

Comment: Objects cannot be passed to va_list, but you can (and should) move to `ostream`. Try `boost::format` (or write some yourself, I did it). Another help could be by creating overloaded `c_str(arg)` helper to accept both C string and C++ strings to return C string for both and always use `strcpy(c, c_str(whatever))`.

Comment: @firda, your comment is worth upgrading to an answer.

Comment: The problem is I cannot change the library usage, just the library. I cannot change the printf call, just the type sent to it

Answer (score 2):

You can pass only **trivially-copyable** PODs to `...`.

You could do

```
struct wrapper { const char * it; };

wrapper it{"hello"};
printf("%s", it);
```

But the problem is, you cannot manage memory. Once you try to add constructor and destructor to alloc/free the memory, you will be faced with an error.

**error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘class mystr’ through ‘...’**

You can help yourself with:

```
const char * c_str(const char * it) { return it; }
const char * c_str(const std::string& it) { return it.c_str(); }

const char * cstr = "hello";
std::string cppstr = "world";

printf("%s %s!", c_str(cstr), c_str(cppstr));
```

Or use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/format/index.html) (or similar for [`ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)). And you should use ostream/format for C++ (type-safe).

Comment: +1 for the c_str() overloads. I saw your comment first and included it in my answer, but now that you've moved yours to an answer, I'll upvote yours as a courtesy.

Comment: The problem is I cannot change the library usage, just the library. I cannot change the printf call, just the type sent to it.

Comment: @grunt: I saw your comment @MelvinSmith and the answer is the same. You are out of luck, not possible. That simple `wrapper` is the only thing that works (true plain-old-data), but (non-trivial) objects cannot be passed to `...`. You have to search for different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> The problem is with this:
>
> sprintf(c, "%s", ms);
>
> The C "arg_list" functions will not use the
>   char* cast.

There is no cast here. `sprintf(..., "%s")` is not casting `ms` to anything, so it will never call your conversion operator. A cast would be: `sprintf(c, "%s", (const char *)ms)`. Unlike strcpy, va_list doesn't cause a coercion as there is no parameter type.

You can pass objects to va_list functions, but it you need to either explicitly cast the arguments to call the correct type conversion, or use .c_str()

If printf() could implicitly handle C++ objects per its format specifiers, it would certainly already be in the language, since it is probably one of the most desired library functions that didn't map over from C.

If you are set on using printf() and family, simply write:

```
printf("%s", foo.c_str());
```

Or try something like this (as suggested by @firda in a comment):

```
const char * c_str(const std:string &s) { return s.c_str(); }
const char * c_str(const char * s) { return s; }
```

Then you consistently write:

```
printf("%s%s", c_str(foo), c_str(bar));
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot change the library usage, just the library. I cannot change the printf call, just the MyString type

Comment: Ok, I understand. Well, you are out of luck with the sprintf() then, unfortunately, unless you want to write your own sprintf() replacement.

Comment: How can I rewrite the sprintf? it should accept an arg list, and call native sprintf with a repopulated arg list where MyString is properly casted

Comment: There is no easy answer. Some requirements aren't practical. Who needs this functionality? A customer? In what way?

Comment: There is legacy code written in C++ builder (Borland) which needs to be ported to MSVS. If instead of porting HEAPS of code, the borland infrastructure can be emulated much effort will be saved. Amongst other things borland supports types that can be treated both as char* and string. Only porting cavet is the printf functions with the problem descrived above.

Answer (score 1):

Normal C++ variadic functions cannot work with object instances because the values must be bit-copiable (the called function will not know the types of the objects passed at compile time).

With C++11 you can however write a variadic template that takes care of doing the trick of using the call-site type knowledge to unpack the parameters:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int mysprintf(char *buf, const char *fmt) {
    return sprintf(buf, "%s", fmt);
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int mysprintf(char *buf, const char *fmt, const T& x, Args... args) {
    const char *sp = strchr(fmt, '%');
    if (sp) {
        while (fmt < sp) *buf++ = *fmt++;
        std::string fmt1(fmt, fmt+2);
        int sz = sprintf(buf, fmt1.c_str(), x);
        return sz + mysprintf(buf+sz, fmt+2, args...);
    } else {
        fputs("Invalid format string\n", stderr);
        std::abort();
        return 0;
    }
}

template<typename... Args>
int mysprintf(char *buf, const char *fmt, const std::string& x, Args... args) {
    const char *sp = strchr(fmt, '%');
    if (sp) {
        if (sp[1] != 's') {
            fputs("Invalid format string (%s expected)\n", stderr);
            std::abort();
        }
        while (fmt < sp) *buf++ = *fmt++;
        std::string fmt1(fmt, fmt+2);
        int sz = sprintf(buf, fmt1.c_str(), x.c_str());
        return sz + mysprintf(buf+sz, fmt+2, args...);
    } else {
        fputs("Invalid format string\n", stderr);
        std::abort();
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[200];
    std::string foo = "foo";
    const char *bar = "bar";
    int x = 42;

    mysprintf(buf, "foo='%s', bar='%s', x=%i", foo, bar, x);
    printf("buf = \"%s\"\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

NOTE: to keep things simple this code doesn't handle any formatting options or `%` escaping, but allows using `%s` for both naked `char *` and `std::string`.

NOTE2: I'm not saying this is a good idea... just that's possible

Comment: +1 Nice one. Did not examine the code in detail, but the idea is good (similar to [my own format helper for ostreams](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63578/printf-like-formatting-for-stdostream-not-exactly-boostformat)).